# Have hidden ID on types for export/import synchronization

Tags: revit-api

We are doing exports and imports involving Revit files and an external data source.
What is the best approach to ID our objects imported to Revit? The ID values should stay hidden from users of our plugin so they cannot be changed accidentally.

We transfer wall, roof, ceiling and some other types, these types should have an identifier that matches the ones in our external source.

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is Extensible Storage.

https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.23

That link also has some discussion on other options.